# Fourier Cosine Transform $\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Find the Fourier Cosine Transform of the function $f(x)$ given by 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & 0<x<a \\
0, & x>a
\end{cases}$$

Hence find the FCT (Fourier Cosine Transform) of $\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$

FCT: $$\mathcal F_c(f(x))=\sqrt \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty}f(x)\cos(sx)dx=F_c(s)$$

I need to find the FCT using the piecewise material. Any help appreciated

Comment: Your question is incoherent. What is the function for which you search the FCT ? Did you try to find the transform of $f$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think I used the wrong symbol previously, I edited. It should be good now.

Comment: It's still confusing. You want to find the FCT of $\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$ or do you want to show that that FCT of $f(x)$ is $\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$?

Comment: I want to find the FCT of the piecewise function f(x). I believe the $\frac{sin(ax)}{x}$ is there as a hint or help I guess....This is exactly what it says on my sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier Cosine transform of $f(x)$ is $\mathcal F_c\{f(x)\}=F_c(s)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\cos(sx)\mathrm d x$ that is
$$
F_c(s)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{a} \cos(sx)\mathrm d x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left.\frac{\sin(sx)}{s}\right|_0^a=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(as)}{s}
$$
So you have the pair
$$
f(x) \longleftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(as)}{s}
$$
and then the function $g(x)=\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$ has Fourier Cosine transform $$\mathcal F_c\{g(x)\}=G_c(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(s)$$